# Error Running SQL Lite In-Memory Unit Tests in Docker Container

Tags: c#, sqlite, docker, docker-compose, spatial

I am using docker containers to run my XUnit tests in azure-pipeline.  I have a Dockerfile for each .NET Core unit test project.  I followed the pattern detailed here:

[Running your unit tests with Visual Studio Team Services and Docker Compose](https://medium.com/@christiansparre/running-your-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-and-docker-compose-3f82c9b95bf)

I was able to get all unit test projects running except the one where I am using the following references:

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite**
**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite.**

I am using SQLite in memory.

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>()
            .UseSqlite(connection,
            s => {
                s.UseNetTopologySuite();
            }).Options;

        var dbContext = new Context(option, null);
```

Originally, I had setup my DockerFile as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/Infrastructure.Tests
RUN dotnet restore
```

But, I was receiving the following error when building and running in the image:

**"Unable to load shared library 'libsqlite3-mod-spatialite' or one of its dependencies."**

The unit tests run fine in Visual Studio test runner, just not when running in the image.

After research, I changed my Dockerfile to install spatiallite.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/Infrastructure.Tests
RUN dotnet restore

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
```

I received the following new error:

**The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed.**

I tried following Microsoft's suggestions to create a custom SQLitePCLRaw provider when using SQLite with spatial data.

[Microsoft Documentation on Spatial Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#sqlite)

```
public class NativeLibraryAdapter : IGetFunctionPointer
{
    readonly IntPtr _library;

    public NativeLibraryAdapter(string name)
        => _library = NativeLibrary.Load(name);

    public IntPtr GetFunctionPointer(string name)
        => NativeLibrary.TryGetExport(_library, name, out var address)
            ? address
            : IntPtr.Zero;
}

And in my SQLite configuration:



 SQLite3Provider_dynamic_cdecl
                .Setup("sqlite3", new NativeLibraryAdapter("sqlite3"));

            SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLite3Provider_dynamic_cdecl());

            var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            connection.Open();

            var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EmployeeContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection,
                s => {
                    s.UseNetTopologySuite();
                }).Options;
```

Now I am receiving the following error:
**"Unable to load shared library 'sqlite3' or one of its dependencies."**

This occurs in both Visual Studio test runner and when running my Docker image.

At this point, I am not certain if I am taking the correct approach to getting this working.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You might need to `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` too

Comment: Also, now you can just install the `SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3` package and use `SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_sqlite3())` instead of implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem when using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1. In order to run SaptiaLite in my test cases, I have to install these two packages:

```
apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
```

Instead of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite, I have to use

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
- SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3

These packages use system supplied SQLite.

Dockerfile and Sample code can be found here:
https://bitbucket.org/assetic/pipelines-dotnet-sonar-spatialite/src/master/